# How to do not reset search results in Yii zii.widgets.grid.cgridview

Tags: search, yii, zii-widgets

I have zii.widgets.grid.cgridview on admin page, and when I search some records and visit view one of them, and after return to admin page results is reseted. May I save them someway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a suggestion:

First disable Ajax update in your `CGridView`'s view:

```
'ajaxUpdate' => false
```

Now, it sends data via `GET` request. If you save the current `GET`, it would be possible to use the result later. It is accessible with:

```
$_GET['YOUR_MODEL_NAME'];
```

If you want to use it in somewhere else, you can get values from `GET` and put it into a `CDBCriteria`.

Others might offer another way.